# Reasons for why queue notification percentage greater than one

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Was just wondering, for reasons or resources, why PG queue notification percentage, as shown by `pg_notification_queue_usage()`, would be greater than one. Was wondering if there are other reasons besides a transaction that is hung, that can be in active state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) explains:

> There is a queue that holds notifications that have been sent but not yet processed by all listening sessions. If this queue becomes full, transactions calling `NOTIFY` will fail at commit. The queue is quite large (8GB in a standard installation) and should be sufficiently sized for almost every use case. However, no cleanup can take place if a session executes `LISTEN` and then enters a transaction for a very long time.

So perhaps your transaction management needs some improvement, so that you have no long running transactions.